# ML kit take too much Memory [Android]

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to use image content [**onDevice Mode**] to describe some images but it takes too much memory and if I tried many images in the same app it **crashes**.

I don't know why that happens but it always throws **OutOfMemoryError** Exception.
my Images are about 1-2 MB size.

when I googled for the exception I enabled the `android:largeHeap="true"` but still crashes after 2 images try.

I also tried to free memory from vars using `System.gc();` but still, take too much memory.

this is the code I use for doing it onDevice:

in onCreate();
`detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                          .getVisionLabelDetector();`

when click button

```
            detector.detectInImage(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionLabel>>() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(List<FirebaseVisionLabel> labels) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    setResult(labels, "onDevice Result : ", before);

                                    System.gc();
                                }
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
```

can any One help me?

Comment: Sounds like someone is holding onto a reference to the images.  Find what it is an stop them.  Also remember-  if the file is 1-2 MB, the uncompressed image will be many times that.  An uncompressed image is 4*width*height bytes.  A PNG will typically be 3x, a JPG typically 16x.

Comment: the image is `image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);` and bitmap the image what I need to get it's content

Comment: @M_ELsaghier, how did you get the Bitmap object? If you can share more details, we can try to repro. Also, could you test 1) not calling FirebaseML and repeat your operation for multiple images? 2) If the image came from a file, you can try FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath and see if it works fine.  With these experiments, we might be able to isolate where the culprit is. Thanks

Comment: initially, images come from the drawable folder but in future will be from a server side, I tried

Comment: @M_ELsaghier, just saw your comment. Have you tried 1) & 2) I suggested? What's the result? I also tried putting a 37MB image in assets folder and repeatedly do fromBitmap & image labeling, I could not repro the OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I tried them but not work too. I managed to solve it by compress the image to make it's size too low to solve it faster but some details of image lost and get bad labeling data

Comment: @M_ELsaghier You mean you tried 1) as well? Then it probably means your own code is preventing the memory being reclaimed? Maybe you can paste more code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that images quality is too high and didn't compress image

Image Must be compressed before init processing on it